# High performance and scalability for .NET based applications

Tags: .net, performance, caching, scalability, distributed

Is there any other better option that can be used for high performance and scalability except [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx). It includes Microsoft distributed cache for .NET apps (code name “Velocity”) that is used to improve performance of web, composite, and Enterprise .NET applications.

Answer (score 1):

Improving performance is generally achieved by improving multiple areas of computing; RAM, CPU, disk speed / space, data cashing, network latency, horizontal and vertical partitioning, application factoid, compression, etc. If you are interested in improving your performance I would suggest looking at:  http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need NCache to have high performance or scalability.  It looks like a cache-oriented in-memory database, and that's nifty for some applications, but not a general prerequisite for high performance or scalability.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for achieving better performance and scaling in the caching front is via use of both RAM & Disk, specifically, the disk can be used to virtualize the memory, in somewhat like a memory extender fashion to solve scale as memory is scarce. That is, highly optimized, totally reduced mapping overheads. Low footprint, tightly integrated with the data indexing engine w/ direct mapping to disk.

Depending on use-case, there is no point using a caching solution when caching itself hasn't achieved optimal performance & scalability levels due to network & orchestration latencies.

A very good sample implementation of this technique is the new Virtual Cache open source code library, check it out on this link for more details: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/827339/Virtual-Cache.